# Is there a solution set for Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming series?

Tags: algorithms

Is there a solution set for the books in *The Art of Computer Programming* series written by Donald Knuth?

I've found solutions for *Concrete Mathematics* using Google, but not the above series.

Comment: I don't have the books with me right now, but as far as I remember the edition I have, has around 200 pages of exercise solutions at the end of the book.

Comment: @phan801 Thanks for the response but yes... it does contain solution to some problems but not all.

Answer (score 4):

The books contain worked solutions to some exercises and hints to some others. Others are open questions: this is indicated by their difficulty rating, and you shouldn't expect to find worked solutions to them except maybe, for a few, as papers in journals.